# Custom Content Dialog in UWP with 3+ buttons

Tags: c#, dialog, windows-10-universal

I'd like to display a content dialog box that has more than the traditional Primary and Secondary results.  Since I can't override the ContentDialogResult enum and add options to that property, it seems my only choice may be to create my own custom control that works similarly to a ContentDialog.

For additional context:  Often, one might see a Dialog box show up during a computer/app operation, when the action is redundant, i.e. copying files to a folder, the computer generally offers a dialog box with not 2 options, but 4. -> "Yes to All", "No to All", "Yes", "No".  I can't seem to find any cookie cutter ways to take advantage of this seemingly common practice.
I'd like to use it just the same as a normal Content Dialog like so:

```
var dialog = new MyCustomContentDialog();
var result = dialog.ShowAsync();
```

and then return an enum just as the normal ContentDialog but instead have it return 1 of 4 options, not just 2.

Any help or recommendations would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I'd like to display a content dialog box that has more than the traditional Primary and Secondary results.

The [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) has 2 built-in buttons(the primary/secondary button) that let a user respond to the dialog. If you want more buttons to let the user to respond to the dialog, you should be able to achieve this by including these buttons in the content of the dialog.

Following is a simple sample shows how to create and use a custom dialog with 3 button:

**MyCustomContentDialog.xaml**

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="ContentDialogDemo01.MyCustomContentDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ContentDialogDemo01"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="dialog"
Title="Delete">

<!-- Content body -->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Delete file A?" Margin="5" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Yes" x:Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" Margin="5,0" Width="100" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="No" x:Name="btn2" Click="btn2_Click" Margin="5,0" Width="100" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Cancle" x:Name="btn3" Click="btn3_Click" Margin="5,0" Width="100" />
</Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

**MyCustomContentDialog.xaml.cs**

```
namespace ContentDialogDemo01
{
// Define your own ContentDialogResult enum
public enum MyResult
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Cancle,
    Nothing
}

public sealed partial class MyCustomContentDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public MyResult Result { get; set; }

    public MyCustomContentDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Result = MyResult.Nothing;
    }

    // Handle the button clicks from dialog
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = MyResult.Yes;
        // Close the dialog
        dialog.Hide();
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = MyResult.No;
        // Close the dialog
        dialog.Hide();
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = MyResult.Cancle;
        // Close the dialog
        dialog.Hide();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code to show the custom dialog and use returned custom result:

```
private async void ShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Show the custom dialog
    MyCustomContentDialog dialog = new MyCustomContentDialog();
    await dialog.ShowAsync();

    // Use the returned custom result
    if (dialog.Result == MyResult.Yes)
    {
        DialogResult.Text = "Dialog result Yes.";
    }
    else if (dialog.Result == MyResult.Cancle)
    {
        DialogResult.Text = "Dialog result Canceled.";
    }
    else if (dialog.Result == MyResult.No)
    {
        DialogResult.Text = "Dialog result NO.";
    }
}
```

Here is the [entire sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!120&authkey=!AJbyfJtqUgZI5XE&ithint=file%2czip). Following is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness - the `ContentDialog` class by default actually offers three buttons - `Primary`, `Secondary` and `Close`. Close is what is triggered when the user presses escape, but if you set `CloseButtonText` the button will show up as the third button in the dialog's footer.